# Node.js streams not flushing between uses. How to flush?

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer

I'm having an issue with Node.js Streams/Buffers where they aren't being closed/flushed following first use. I have a read stream created from `fs.createReadStream` that I am piping to a custom write stream. The `highWaterMark` for each chunk is ~2MB (this is important). When I initially stream through a ~3MB file, it is handled in 2 chunks by my stream, first a ~2MB chunk, then a ~1MB chunk. This is expected.

On the second file that I pass through, the first chunk is only ~1MB. This is an issue. When I add up the bytes piped, I can see that clearly after the first file, the streams/buffers associated were not cleaned up properly. This can be shown with the following math:

The final chunk that is transferred of the first file is 875,837 bytes. The first chunk of the *next* file that is transferred is 1,221,316 bytes (expected: 2,097,152 bytes). When you add 875,837 to 1,221,316, you get 2,097,153, which is the high water mark I mentioned earlier (with an off by one error).

Here is the code I've got:

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const maximalChunkedTransferSize = 2*1024*1024; // 2MB (Minimum amount, Autodesk recommends 5MB).

    const pathToFile = await bucketManagement.locationOfBucketZip(bucketEntity.name);
    let readFileStream = fs.createReadStream(pathToFile, { highWaterMark: maximalChunkedTransferSize });

    let writeStream = new HttpAutodeskPutBucketObjectWriteStream(accessToken, bucketEntity);
    readFileStream.pipe(writeStream);

    writeStream.on("finish", () => {
        resolve(writeStream.urn);
    });
    writeStream.on("error", err => reject("Putting the file into the bucket failed. " + err.message));
});
```

I've tried calling `.destroy()` on both the read and write stream. I've tried calling `.end()`, `.unpipe()`. None of these have worked. How can I destroy/flush the stream and/or underlying buffer so that the first chunk of the next file is the expected 2MB?

Comment: Did yo ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

[`writeStream.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#writableendchunk-encoding-callback) will allow you to (optionally) send a final chunk and close the stream. It is meant to be called before you trigger off of the [`writeStream.on("finish")`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#event-finish) event, which flushes the stream.